# javascript stopwatch user input

Tags: javascript, html

does anybody know why my counter keep counting from the beginning since i hit resume button?

```js
var minute;
var second;
var audio;
var interval;
var button = HTMLButtonElement.value = "Resume"

function yok() {
  document.getElementById("btninput").disabled = true
  minute = document.getElementById("minute").value
  second = document.getElementById("second").value

  interval = setInterval(tambah, 1000)

  function tambah() {
    second--
    if (minute != 0 && second == -1) {
      minute--
      second = 59
    } else if (minute == 0 && second == 0) {
      clearInterval(interval)
      document.getElementById("hasill").innerHTML = "Finish!!!"
      document.getElementById("btninput").disabled = false
    }
    document.getElementById("hasil").innerHTML = minute + " : " + second
  }
}



function stop() {
  document.getElementById("btninput").disabled = false
  clearInterval(interval)

  document.getElementById("btninput").innerHTML = button;
}
```

```html
<p data-component="head">TIMER</p>
<input type="number" id="minute" placeholder="minute" style="width: 65px;" data-component="minute">
<input type="number" id="second" placeholder="seconds" style="width: 69px;" max="60" data-component="second">
<p id="hasil" data-component="hasil">00</p>
<p id="hasill" data-component="hasill"></p>
<audio src="ding-sound-effect_2.mp3" id="sound" data-component="sound"></audio>
<button onclick="yok()" data-component="button" id="btninput">start</button>
<button onclick="stop()" id="stop">stop</button>
```

Comment: [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: When you click resume, `second = 59;` gets hit.

Comment: Dear Tulus, You have used id="husill" on two <p>'s remove from one

Comment: In function yok() you are setting values of variables 'minute' and 'second' from inputs which are not changing in interval.

Comment: In yok() function, the values of minute and second is empty string "", you have not as they don't have any value in them yet. Which makes the if() condition to also fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues, that I have seen so far.

1. The initial values for **minutes** and **seconds** is not set initially in your code which creates bugs into your code.
2. I don't find any use of  **minute** and **second** input fields when they are no longer used in your code. (*I have perhaps used those input fields and added my hour field as well)*

I have made some changes and provided a better Timer logic as per conversions between hours and minutes and seconds. Go through the code provided and see if it works fine for you. I have removed unwanted code (You can use the same logic in any manner you like).

You basic Timer is ready though :)

```js
let second = 0;
let minute = 0;
let hour = 0;
var interval;
var button = (HTMLButtonElement.value = "Resume");

function yok() {
  document.getElementById("btninput").disabled = true;

  interval = setInterval(tambah, 1000);
}

function tambah() {
  // if (minute != 0 && second == -1) {
  //   minute--;
  //   second = 59;
  // } else if (minute == 0 && second == 0) {
  //   clearInterval(interval);
  //   document.getElementById("hasill").innerHTML = "Finish!!!";
  //   document.getElementById("btninput").disabled = false;
  // }
  // document.getElementById("hasil").innerHTML = minute + " : " + second;
  second++;
  document.getElementById("second").value = second;
  if (second === 60) {
    minute = minute + 1;
    document.getElementById("minute").value = minute;
    second = 0;

    if (minute === 60) {
      hour = hour + 1;
      document.getElementById("hour").value = minute;
      minute = 0;
    }

    // You can take it forward from here onnwards
  }
}

function stop() {
  document.getElementById("btninput").disabled = false;
  clearInterval(interval);

  document.getElementById("btninput").innerHTML = button;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Timer in Javascript</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p data-component="head">TIMER</p>

    <input
      type="number"
      id="hour"
      placeholder="hour"
      style="width: 65px;"
      data-component="hour"
    />
    <span>h</span>

    <input
      type="number"
      id="minute"
      placeholder="minute"
      style="width: 65px;"
      data-component="minute"
    />
    <span>m</span>
    <input
      type="number"
      id="second"
      placeholder="seconds"
      style="width: 69px;"
      max="60"
      data-component="second"
    />
    <span>s</span>
    <!-- <p id="hasil" data-component="hasil">00</p> -->
    <br />
    <br />
    <button onclick="yok()" data-component="button" id="btninput">start</button>
    <button onclick="stop()" id="stop">stop</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @TulusIbrahim You are most welcome. I am a React Developer. Any time you need any help, you can email me : emmeiwhite@gmail.com or whatsapp me 07006312148 . Never stop learning, keep going. You can also check  my many repositories from github and learn from the code there ... https://github.com/emmeiwhite

Answer (score 1):

When you press resume, `yok()` is invoked. Which resets the `minute` and `second` on

```
minute = document.getElementById("minute").value
second = document.getElementById("second").value
```

You could add a condition to handle case for resume.

```
  if (document.getElementById("btninput").innerHTML !== button){
    minute = document.getElementById("minute").value;
    second = document.getElementById("second").value;
  }
```

---

**EDIT:** 
So to explain more clearly, you should keep in mind that the resume button still has onclick event set to `yok()` (since you only changed the innerHTML from `start` to `resume`). 
So what happens if you press resume? Well, `yok()` function will be executed, and runs the line

```
minute = document.getElementById("minute").value
second = document.getElementById("second").value
```

which sets the value of `minute` and `second` to whatever is in the input field (basically resets the timer).

So what has to be done, is to check if the button is set to the start button state, or the resume button state. So just like how I did above, the simplest way (although not the cleanest) you can check if the innerHTML on the button says 'resume' or not.

---

Also, as ImranRafiqRather mentioned, it might be a better idea to set a default value of `minute` and `second`.

I suggest doing something like

```
  minute = document.getElementById("minute").value || 0;
  second = document.getElementById("second").value || 0;
```

which ensures that if the elements' value were falsy, the code will still set the variables to 0 (you might want to read about falsy values and `||` (or) syntax, it might look weird but yes, javascript is a weird language :P).

Comment: could you get me a whole code that is correct, i still confused

Comment: @Kenta Nomoto  In the first place the minutes and seconds have never been set. The contains empty strings. The program is still behaving oddly... Starting seconds from -1 to --

Comment: @Tulsus Ibrahim. If you check your code and use a console.log(minute) and console.log(second) you will see your minute and second contain empty strings.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Well, that happens when you don't give any input to the input field. That problem can be solved by giving a default value.

Comment: @Kento Nomoto Indeed ! So, we have to make sure we set the initial values for seconds, and minutes and also the hours( that what  I believe) and figure out a logic work on. Let me take some time to debug Tulus Ibrahim's code.

Comment: @Kento Nomoto I have just provided the logic needed for the timer to work correctly. Please have a look. Changed some code and added my logic :)

Comment: @Tulus Ibrahim I have re-written your code a bit , and now the timer is working fine. Check my Answer. Enjoy. Do please rate me if my code helps you. Thanks :)